# How to get around PHP memory limit

Tags: php, mysql, memory

So, we have a fun scenario. Our client has a custom CMS that we built them. One of the sections allows batch-processing of records, so it's displayed as a table. Each record has a few text fields, and one select box. This worked just fine when the database was small, but now there are over 10,000 records in the table, and generating those select boxes is killing our PHP memory limit.

I'm not looking for someone to write code for me, but to give me an idea of a better way to do this.

Here's how it works:

1) Make a database call that generates the list of options to populate the select boxes. It's returned from PHP to the front end as a huge concatenated string variable called `$topping_images`, like so:

```
<option>Select an image</option><option value="cheese_mozz_ML.png">cheese_mozz_ML.png</option><option value="cheese_mozz_ML_HT.png">cheese_mozz_ML_HT.png</option><option value="cheese_mozz_ML_pan.png">cheese_mozz_ML_pan.png</option><option value="cheese_mozz_ML_SC.png">cheese_mozz_ML_SC.png</option>
```

2) Make a database call that returns the records to be displayed; comes back as an array called `$toppings`.

3) Generate our table like so:

```
<? 
$x = 0;
foreach ($toppings as $topping) : ?>
    <tr>
        <td style="width:25%">
            <input type="text" id="t_name<?= $x ?>" value="<?= $topping['topping_name'] ?>" />
        </td>

        <td style="width:29%">
            <input type="hidden" id="topp_img_hdn<?= $x ?>" value="<?= $topping['image_path']; ?>" />
            <select id="topp_img<?= $x ?>">
                <?= $topping_images ?>
            </select>
        </td>
    <? $x++; ?>
<? endforeach; ?>
```

We cannot change our memory limit (either via php.ini or by using `ini_set('memory_limit')`), and our client absolutely refuses to consider pagination to allow a smaller set of data to be sent to each page load.

Am I missing a really obvious way to cut down the processing time and memory usage here?

Comment: Are the tables indexed properly? 10K rows is *nothing* to MySQL

Comment: I'm guessing using a newer, more efficient PHP version is probably out of the question too?

Comment: @JayBlanchard - yes, the tables are indexed. If I error=log things out, the database call finishes in no time. The issue is the rendering of the page.

Comment: @tadman - did you see the part where I said our client refuses to consider pagination? This is not an option for us; we need to find a way to do it all on one page, or we don't get paid.

Comment: If your client is stubbornly refusing, you're going to have to paginate anyway and do some assembly client-side by combining the pages back into a singular gigantic page. You could emit JSON on the server side and do a lot of the expensive table wrangling using something on the client.

Comment: Also, why can't you change the memory limit? Is the client insistent it remains on a really crappy shared hosting account?

Comment: @MatthewDaly - we are actually working on upgrading our PHP, but we're a very high-traffic site, and there are plugins to other systems that don't have versions that work with newer versions of PHP. This is something that needs to be fixed before we get PHP updated.

Comment: @tadman - it's nice that you can afford to be self-righteous. I can't. I'm a developer in a company with a multi-million dollar client. There's no saying no to them; if I try, I'll just be replaced.

Comment: You're running up against limits here you've stated you cannot change. I've offered you an out: Paginate but do it in a way that's invisible to the client. They're not going to pop open the web inspector to see how you solved the problem, they're just going to see that it works.

Comment: How many queries is it actually running? I'm wondering if it's the n+1 problem.

Comment: On what iteration of the loop do you hit the limit?

Comment: There are only two actual queries running - one to return the toppings string, and one to return the editable records.

Comment: If these toppings change infrequently you'd actually see a huge boost in performance if you could render it out as one or more JSON documents that are cached and loaded on demand by your pages. Zero database calls is always faster and more memory efficient. There's dozens of JavaScript templating solutions, like [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com) that can easily convert JSON back into HTML.

Comment: @tadman - that's an interesting idea. Unfortunately, we're already using a templating engine, and I don't know that I can combine Handlebars with the existing engine.

I hate being that person who asks for help and then rejects every solution, but we're in a situation here that requires a "pure" solution (i.e. no extra libraries, engines, etc.)

Comment: Templating system always have a way to override the default escape characters because so many other templating systems use a similar syntax.

Comment: @chris85 - it runs out of memory at around 1700 out of 10,000. Pretty bad.

Comment: How about implementing infinite scroll? That's technically pagination but would require less of the user

Comment: @MatthewDaly - I'm aware of that, but the complexity of mixing templating systems is not something we can take on.

Comment: @MatthewDaly - I admit I'm not familiar with how to implement infinite scroll. That would definitely be better than what we're doing now.

Comment: If you've already got one that's client-side, try and leverage that. You could also roll your own super-simple one that behaves like Handlebars using a regular expression, it's actually about two lines of code to get something superficially similar: `html.replace(/{{(\w+)}}/g, function(_,a) { return values[a] })` where `values` is a simple JSON object of values.

Comment: It's not that complex. I've combined Angular 1 and Laravel Blade several times without issue

Comment: i didnt know angular 1 and blade shipped with expression engine...

Comment: Here you go - https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-infinite-scrolling-demos/

Comment: Hmm. Infinite scroll looks interesting, and I've found a few blogs about how to implement. Am I correct in assuming that if a user does a control-F search in their browser, it will only return records that have actually been rendered already? That may be a deal-breaker.

Comment: @castis That was just an example...

Comment: Yes, that's correct. However, you could implement an AJAX search for that use case.

Comment: Most infinite scroll systems are lazy loading by design, but there's nothing stopping you from making them aggressive and loading everything. You just change the trigger condition from "user scrolls" to "not all data is loaded". It will take a moment to load all the data, but at least the page will pop up faster in its initial form, and by the time they do a search hopefully everything is fully loaded.

Comment: At the risk of being called names out of frustration, as a senior dev its your job to advise on proper solutions to a given problem.

Comment: Also, I'm very dubious about the need for Ctrl-F to find stuff in a world where [90% of users don't know about Ctrl-F](http://www.smh.com.au/technology/technology-news/only-one-in-10-know-what-ctrlf-does--here-are-shortcuts-you-should-know-20111130-1o69d.html).

Comment: @castis - yup, you're being that person. I can advise. That doesn't mean the client accepts the advice. In the end, they're paying, and we have to do what they are asking for.

Comment: @MatthewDaly - these particular clients are very aware of ctrl-F, and specifically stated that any solution we come up with must still work with ctrl-F.

Comment: It sounds to me like the underlying problem is that your employer has a toxic relationship with this company. They're ignoring your advice in favour of their own people and placing arbitrary and ridiculous barriers in your way. Regarding the Ctrl-F thing, do they not realise how few web apps would work with that(Gmail, for example) and how few people use it? If it's an internal portal they might have a leg to stand on, but otherwise they wouldn't

Comment: @MatthewDaly - you're not wrong. It's not a great relationship, but they pay *big*, so leadership keeps them around. And this is technically an internal portal. They're a top-3 pizza company, and the CMS allows them to configure content that displays on the customer-facing site.

Comment: Ok, well I think having an AJAX search is your best bet under the circumstances. It sounds like showing everything on one page has become impractical, and offering an alternative that still meets their needs is the main way to go. If it doesn't change often, maybe caching the data in Redis or Memcached might help?

Comment: Also, possibly pre-warm the cache at some point so it's always served from the cache?

Answer (score 1):

yup. stop using fetchAll(). keep just 1 row, the row that you're actually working on, in memory at any given time.

```
$rows=$db->query("SELECT * FROM tbl")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($rows as $row){...}
```

this could use a lot of memory if there's a lot of rows, as it keeps all rows in memory at the same time.

now, this nearly equivalent code,

```
foreach($db->query("SELECT * FROM tbl",PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row){...}
```

would only keep 1 row, the row that you're using, in memory at any given time (except lags in the garbage collector, im guessing max 2 rows at any given time)

Comment: We're not using fetchAll. And the CMS uses templating, so there's no way to do it this way that I can see. It would be my preferred solution, but ExpressionEngine doesn't work that way.

Comment: @EmmyS bummer. guess maybe you could tweak your CMS to flush more often, rather than output buffer everything until the end in-ram, then... btw, are you using ob_start() & co to push everything out at the end? in that case, you could use a custom ob_start callback function that stores the output text out-of-ram on disk (like in a tmpfile() )

Comment: or maybe you could bypass the CMS for this specific page and create it manually?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest:

- Return `$topping_images` as an array to the frontend rather than rendered HTML
- Use select2 to generate the select boxes with a JSONized version of that data (https://select2.github.io/options.html#data).

So, for example:

```
<? 
$x = 0;
foreach ($toppings as $topping) : ?>
    <tr>
        <td style="width:25%">
            <input type="text" id="t_name<?= $x ?>" value="<?= $topping['topping_name'] ?>" />
        </td>

        <td style="width:29%">
            <input type="hidden" id="topp_img_hdn<?= $x ?>" value="<?= $topping['image_path']; ?>" />
            <select class="topping-images" id="topp_img<?= $x ?>"></select>
        </td>
    </tr>
<? $x++; ?>
<? endforeach; ?>
<script>
    $(".topping-images").select2({
        data: <?= json_encode($topping_images); ?>
    });
</script>
```

Another benefit you get with this solution is that this huge list now becomes searchable.

**EDIT: You can achieve a similar effect with plain old jQuery**

I haven't tested this, and it's definitely not the most elegant solution, but it looks like it should work.

```
<script>
var optionsArr = <?= json_encode($topping_images); ?>;

var options = optionsArr.map(function(topping){
    return '<option value="' + topping.id + '">' + topping.name + '</option>';
}).join('');

$('.topping-images').html(options);
</script>
```

Comment: If you can get `select2` working properly it's pretty snazzy.

Comment: We actually have used select2 in other projects, but this client is a doozy, and refuses to allow us to use external libraries, plugins, etc. aside from jQuery in general.

Comment: You could still use jQuery to render plain select boxes with the JSONized data.

Comment: Oh, giod god. They ban the use of Javascript libraries other than jQuery? On what basis?

Comment: @MatthewDaly - depends on who you talk to. Some claim it's security; others say other libraries aren't sufficiently stable; some say it's Monday and June. Again, they're a multi-million dollar client, and although we can advise and suggest, they have internal "developers" who they give the final say to.

Comment: @GeoffOliver - I'm trying your plain jQuery solution, and am not sure I'm doing it correctly. I've never used the `.map` function, and when I add it to my code (pretty much copy/paste directly from your post), I get an error that `optionsArr.map is not a function`. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: what the hell? multi-million dollar client that can't affoard more ram? must be a bunch of idiots calling the shots on the IT-side.. sigh, good luck. reminds me of https://youtu.be/5GpOfwbFRcs?t=53s

Comment: @hanshenrik - it's more like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BKorP55Aqvg&list=FLFNma9mNp5uBdASvOMq_iiw&index=11

Comment: @EmmyS - is `optionsArr` an array? i.e. is the `json_encode`d result an array, or an object? If it's not an array, you can do a `for(..in..)` loop to iterate over the properties of the object like so - `for(var t in optionsArr){ var topping = optionsArr[t]; /* build the <options>...</options> */ }`

Comment: @GeoffOliver - it's neither. All `json_encode` does to the string I posted in the OP is add slashes to it, as demonstrated http://codepad.org/wTQlCp43. That's the whole problem - how can I get that string split into a real array or object?

Comment: Ah, that's because you didn't follow step 1, "Return `$topping_images` as an array to the frontend rather than rendered HTML" :-) If you can get `$topping_images` as an array rather than a string of <option>...</option>, then `json_encode` will turn it into a JSON array

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you still need a solution for this, but I stumbled across a possibility today...

It's quite likely that the problem is in the foreach loop as it has to load the entire dataset into memory.
 [Generators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php) allow you to iterate over a dataset with a much smaller memory footprint, and so *may* alleviate this issue.